# Looking for close reason

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

I just saw [How to compile a c++ program using the terminal on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901180/how-to-compile-a-c-program-using-the-terminal-on-a-mac). That question has 11 (**eleven**) downvotes, but no close requests?!

Now I am wondering: is the question actually "too broad"; or just "OK", but well, bad?

To me, this one example looks "too broad"; but finding that there are so many downvotes; but no close requests; that shades doubt for me.

So the "more generic" question is probably: is a significant number of votes (positive, or negative) a good indication that the question has been assessed "correctly" by others?

( I can understand that 3 or 5 people come up with a "strange" decision; but 11? )

Comment: If you think it is too broad, just vote to close. If not, don't vote. Just because a question has a lot of downvotes doesn't mean it is off-topic. I'm not sure why this requires meta input; is there a more generic issue you wanted to address where this post is an example?

Comment: Otherwise, you are just drawing the meta effect onto random posts on the site.

Comment: Mainly to understand how to react to this one.

Comment: Can you make it more generic then? What is it about the post that makes you hesitate to vote one way or the other? Can you rework it such that it doesn't require that specific singular example (are there more such posts fitting a pattern, for example)?

Comment: I tried ... but as you might guess; I am not exactly sure myself.

Comment: Note that a post *quality* and post *being on topic* are two different axis. A post can be on-topic and bad, and be off-topic and beautifully documented and researched. So no, votes are not a great indicator of being on or off topic.

Comment: Well, that was intentional.  No longer focusing on experts-exchange.com, the company is competing with Yahoo Answers now.  "How is babby formed" is an on topic question.  As I noted in your previous question, pick anything.  Nobody will hold it against you.  The color of the garbage bag does not matter when you put out the trash.

Comment: @MartijnPieters topically is one of the 4 close reasons.

Comment: @Braiam: that makes no sense. What is 'topically' and what has that got to do with the score of a post?

Comment: @MartijnPieters "topical(ly): pertaining to the **subject of** a discourse, composition, or the like." in other words: the scope of the site (whenever is on topic or not) is 1 of the 4 close reasons. Being too broad doesn't mean that the question is outside SO scope. A question could be in the dead center of the scope, but still is be too broad.

Comment: @HansPassant That message is better to understand than the other one ;-) ... but still: the color of the bag matters to the OP. If 5 people give him a wrong close reason, that might cause a lot of unnecessary work/frustration on the other end.

Comment: That question got flagged twice for closure which bumped it into the CV queue but it never ended up reviewed before they expired... (there's even a possible dupe suggested)

Comment: The OP is a *very* small cog in the SO wheel.  We write Q+A for the next thousand programmers that struggle with the problem stated in the question.  Or hundreds of thousands, happens all the time.  Big unhumble goals, it made the site very successful.  When the site gets overloaded with crap like this then that mission gets lost.  And it will be *you* that can't get help you when you need it because all of the experts quit contributing.

Comment: @Braiam you're thinking of topicality when the more accurate word would be pertinence. Martijn is saying that quality and pertinence are not necessarily linked. Questions can be pertinent but also poor quality, impertinent and high quality, or any combination thereof.

Comment: @TinyGiant Are you aware that what you said made no sense? I was rebutting Martijn "Just because a question has a lot of downvotes **doesn't mean it is off-topic**" assertion: a question can be closed by other reasons other than not being within the scope of the site.

Comment: @Braiam "Off topic" is a term very commonly used on stack overflow to refer to questions which qualify for a close reason.

Comment: @gnat I was just about to write another question ... which your DUP exactly answered. Thanks for the timely input ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the asker doesn't know how to change the current working directory in the terminal.

Arguably, "too broad" fits here simply because the asker needs a lot of prerequisite questions answered before they'll be able to make sense of the answer to this one.

But I doubt that's why the question got downvoted. My guess would be that seeing someone obviously following a chapter one tutorial and already skipping steps is... Frustrating. It bodes ill for their future here, as does the effort that has been wasted in the comments.

Downvoting and close-voting are often orthogonal; one does not need to lead to another.

In comments, Braiam expressed surprise that such basic information would need to be conveyed to a beginning programmer; I must confess that I'm far too many years removed from that state to know what programming introductions are like these days, but a cursory check of related questions on Stack Overflow suggests "not great". With this in mind, I've re-closed the question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/how-to-run-c-c-in-a-unix-console-mac-terminal), and would encourage others to find and mark similar artifacts as well - remember, the easiest question to resolve is the one that doesn't have to be asked.

Comment: "My guess would be that seeing someone obviously following a chapter one tutorial and already skipping steps is... Frustrating" If a C++ tutorial has to explain where to execute commands... I guess I figured why I hate writing tutorials.

Comment: It's been years since I picked up an introductory programming book, but I do seem to recall that once upon a time they did have rudimentary instructions on how to use a command line. Given Apple's historical userbase, I would be shocked if that was no longer the case for OS X. Note that the confusion here mostly arises from a disconnect between the graphical interface and the terminal; a budding programmer entering their first listing in, say, `ed` would tend to find themselves already in the correct location to compile and run the program. Of course, this also necessitates further digression.

Comment: Teaching beginning programmers how to use their operating environment is rightfully off-topic for Stack Overflow. We are a site for "professional and enthusiast programmers". You are expected to bring *prerequisite* knowledge to the table. I don't know what beginning programming books teach, either, but that isn't our mission. (I can guess that they spend the first few chapters teaching you how to use your OS, considering the titles are things like "Unix Programming with C" and "Program Windows Using C++ in 3 Easy Steps". There's no other reason why language books would be platform-specific.)

Answer (score 0):

> That question has 11 (eleven) downvotes, but no close requests?!

Because, not every question about software development is a SO question.

The down votes are indicating three things at the same time: lack of research effort, being unclear and not useful. The lack of close votes could be because while there are two help page that defines what questions should be asked on SO, one is more relied upon than the other: the [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page, and the [don't ask](http://What%20types%20of%20questions%20should%20I%20avoid%20asking?) page. This could be the reason why people choose to down vote more than close vote when there are valid reasons to vote to close in the other page (ignoring the obvious fact that there are many more users that can down vote compared to close voting).

While a question could fit the on topic conditions, if it fails the "don't ask" it should be closed (probably with more prejudice). A question that is not clear, that is opinion based or too broad, could be a perfectly valid question about software development, yet these are closed by their respective close reasons.

The reason you seem to be for is:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

This could be case of that question (just that OP hasn't figured it out). If we have to explain to the OP how to execute commands in a shell (something that isn't programming related), how that relates to directory structures and work step by step until why clang complains that it can't find the file, seems too much ground to cover for something that the OP should have learned first. We could also argue that is unclear, since the OP doesn't specify from which directory he executes the g++ command (without reading the comments). With that information you could decide whenever there's sufficient elements to write an answer.